# Serialize multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, serialization

I have the following dataframes:

```
sales1 = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(sales1)

sales2 = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Apr': 150, 'May': 200, 'Jun': 140},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Apr': 200, 'May': 210, 'Jun': 215},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Apr': 50,  'May': 90,  'Jun': 95 }]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sales2)
```

I want to efficiently serialize both dataframes in one file so I can just upload that file, later, and still keep the dataframes separated.

Comment: use the `pickle` library

Comment: the suggested duplicate answer does not answer the question, in particular it does not talk about saving the two dataframes into one file, nor how to keep the dataframes separate in the one file.